# Where do I place the adverb "massively"?

Tags: word-order

Which of the two sentences sounds better to you?

I'm thinking "massively" should go AFTER the verb seeing that it is an adverb of manner (as per [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position))

The number of people with serious psychological problems due to overusing social media has been massively growing.

The number of people with serious psychological problems due to overusing social media has been growing massively.

Comment: He was running fast / He was fast running. // He was playing amazingly / He was amazingly playing (no commas).

Comment: At one time "has been massively growing" would have been considered an exapmle of a split infinitve and, therefore, incorrect. Such a prosciption is considered inappropriate these days but personally I prefer the adjective to follow the verb in this case.